Simple example of Bayesian probability, picking from a bucket
Bowl I contains six red chips and four blue chips. Five of these 10 chips are selected at random and without replacement and put in bowl II, which was originally empty. One chip is then drawn at random from bowl II. Given that this chip is blue, find the conditional probability that two red chips and three blue chips are transferred from bowl I to bowl II.
Using Bayesian:
$P(A \mid B)=\frac{P(B \mid A) \cdot P(A)}{P(B)}$
Event A is 2 red and 3 blue.
Event B is choosing 1 blue.
\begin{aligned} & P(A)=\frac{\binom{6}{2} \cdot\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{10}{5}}=\frac{60}{252} \\ & P(\bar{A})=1-P(A)=\frac{192}{252}\end{aligned}
Next I have that $P(B|A) = \frac{3}{5}$
$P(B)=P(B \mid A) \cdot P(A)+P(B \mid \hat{A}) \cdot P(\bar{A})=\frac{3}{5} \times \frac{60}{252}+\frac{7}{5} \times \frac{192}{252}$
Now 8/5 is found by looking at complement of A. The calc is as follows:
4/5+2/1*1/5 = 7/5.
Using Bayesian formula and plugging in these values I get 1524/1260 as answer but I am not in the ballpark of what my teacher is stating. What have I done wrong?

Not following.  How could the probability be greater than $1$?

There are five possible cases for what was drawn initially, as you might have drawn $0,1,2,3,4$ blue chips. You need to compute the probability of each case, and also the conditional probability that, given the case, you then drew a blue chip.  The denominator must use all the cases.

Where the $7/5$ number comes out from?

@lulu Guess in this case you don't need to evaluate each case, since the $P(B)$ is equivalent to draw directly a blue chip from Bowl I.

@nicola  Yes, the computation  of the denominator is easy.  I can't follow the computation shown in the post.  In particular, $P(B,|,\overline A)$ is certainly not \frac 75$.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline\\
Blues (B_i)\;in\; Bowl\; H & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
P(B_i\;/252) & 6 & 60 & 120 & 60 & 6\\ \hline
P(One\; blue\; chosen) & 0 & 1/5 & 2/5 & 3/5 & 4/5\\ \hline\end{array}$
P($3$ blues in bowl H | blue chosen) $$=\dfrac{P(b_3\; in\; bowl\; H) \cap P(blue\;chosen)}{P(blue\;chosen)}$$
$$=\dfrac{P(b_3\; in\; bowl\; H) \cap P(blue\;chosen)}{\sum_{i=0}^4[ P(b_i\;in\; bowl\; H\;).P(blue\;chosen\mid b_i\; in\;bowl)}$$
$$= \dfrac{60\cdot\frac35}{0+60\cdot\frac15 +120\cdot\frac25+60\cdot\frac35+6\cdot\frac45} = \dfrac5{14}$$
